# Kotlin classes with underscores

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

Please explain me what is the purpose and meaning of classes like `StringsKt__StringsKt` (i.e. doubled class name with one or more underscores in between) and, similarly, `StringsKt__StringsJVMKt`?

Strings are not the only example, there are many others too. I see them when looking into the structure of the `classes.dex` file in my .apk.

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW1UZ.png)

I'm asking because I faced a situation where I had to explicitly state some of them in my proguard-rules. The app crashed without it.

Comment: Those are likely generated, I can't find any reference to a single class by that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a generated file. A file like that will be generated if there are **several Kotlin files named with same `JvmName`**.

Let's take [Strings.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Strings.kt) and [StringNumberConversions.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringNumberConversions.kt) as an example:

```
// StringNumberConversions.kt
@file:kotlin.jvm.JvmMultifileClass
@file:kotlin.jvm.JvmName("StringsKt")
...

// Strings.kt
@file:kotlin.jvm.JvmMultifileClass
@file:kotlin.jvm.JvmName("StringsKt")
...
```

Both of them have `@file:kotlin.jvm.JvmName("StringsKt")`, so `StringsKt` and `StringsKt__StringNumberConversionsKt` are generated to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected something like this. Strange thing I have to write `-keep class kotlin.collections.MapsKt* { *; }` (with the asterisk at the end) in proguard rules to make my program work.